# Troubles with changing color of hyperlink

Tags: html, css

In CSS, I'm trying to change the properties of a hyperlink.

```
a:link { color: #000000;}
a:hover { color: #582999; }
```

The problem I'm having is that it is changing properties of my nav bar which also uses a href. Is there a way I can put them in their separate classes so I can have more than one style? I have put my navbar in its separate class using `class="navclass"`

Comment: umm, like `a.navclass:hover` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `:not()` pseudo selector.

```
a:not(.navclass){

}
a:not(.navclass):hover{

}
```

Comment: @Popcorn727 i recommend you take a look at the other answers as well. if there will be many `a` elements you do not wish to apply the style, `jeremywoertink` and `jmore009` answers would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Set them how you want globally like you're doing:

```
a:link { color: #000000;}
a:hover { color: #582999; }
```

and in your nav bar just override them with something else:

```
.navclass a:link { color: #FFF;}
.navclass a:hover { color: #F00; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just have the anchors inside your nav use different styles

```
a:link { color: #000000;}
a:hover { color: #582999; }
.navclass a { color: #ffffff; }
```